# CFFTP adds username to the file i'm trying to get

Tags: coldfusion, ftp

I'm FTPing into a remote server with CFFTP and trying to grab a file.  I know the file exists because I can grab it using a native windows FTP command line.  The original command line goes something like this:

```
get 'ur.urpyt005.series23.extract' C:\downloads\remote.txt
```

I'm converting this to a ColdFusion task and am using the following to get the file:

```
<cfftp action="getfile" 
    server="ftp.remote.com" 
    username="remoteuser" 
    password="*******" 
    remotefile="ur.urpyt005.series23.extract"
    localfile="C:\downloads\remote.txt" 
    stoponerror="true" />
```

When I run the script, the FTP server prepends the username to the file I asked for.  I get the following error:

```
Error: 550 Data set REMOTEUSER.UR.URPYT005.SERIES23.EXTRACT not found .
```

How can I tell it not to append the username?

Comment: Since remote file should be a path to the file, try putting a `/` at the front?

Comment: adding / helped get rid of the username issue, but i'm still getting a message that the file does not exist.  maybe some of the . in the file name are really directories. i need to research more

Comment: hm, so i've found that the actual file name is URPYT005.SERIES23.EXTRACT in the UR folder.  But I still get an error when i change it to:
remotefile="/ur/urpyt005.series23.extract"

Comment: Maybe the path needs to be `/home/remoteuser/ur/urpyt005.series23.extract` - or something similar?

Comment: yes, i think you are right, i need additional path information.  unfortunately i think that path is obscured from me. i will have to inquire with the server admins to find the correct path

Comment: Just use `action="listdir"` to get the list of folders in the root.

Comment: i think the issue is that my ftp account does not have permission to view the root.

Comment: I think you should use a real FTP client to login from the perspective of that user and poke around to see what you can see. Otherwise, the administrators didn't setup the account properly.